# Rails geolocation and users nearby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, geolocation, maps

Hi I would like to implement a function in Rails that serves both to have an autocompletely of the location (I saw that I need the Google API but I have not understood how to do this specifically) and I would like to implement a function for which it suggests a current user list of "nearby" users based on the location they have chosen as their residence.

Can you tell me which gem to use and if there is any example of similar use?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, and we are not going to code everything for you. You should at least have a look at the google-maps gem https://github.com/zilverline/google-maps

and read the maps API docs
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation?hl=en (for Places, Maps, Routes etc...) to see if you find anything that could work for you.

You can also search StackOverflow first to see if you find anything interesting as well!

Maybe once you started coding or understanding some concepts you can come back with a less vague question and we will help you!